# Agent animation disappearing after Service

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to animate the movement of my agent through a production line. It appears on the path up to the first service node, but then it is not visible as it moves to the packaging node. In the flowchart, it is moving correctly. Is there a setting I am missing to keep the agent visible in the animation?[image]

In the packaging block, I have the Agent Location (queue) as the Packaging Node, and the Agent Location (delay) as the packaging path.[image]

Comment: play with the stacking order of the path and the agent animation, it may simply be "below" the path: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/presentation/editing-presentation-shapes.html#changing-stacking-order-position

Comment: Thank you. I checked and the lines are all "sent to back" in the order and the agents still don't appear on the second paths in the animation

Comment: Service block also has a setting to "reset animation" (or similar), play with that

Comment: The fix was to add a node before the main service node. In the Service block, the Agent location (queue) is the queue node (first one) and the Agent location (delay) is the service node (second one). This seemed to unclog the service node in the animation and the agents continued down the conveyor after being serviced.